# Алгоритм построения дерева JSON, зная id и parent id?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть массив объектов со значениями id и parent_id.

```
var obj = [{
        id : 1,
        parent_id : 1,
        text: 'Корень'
    },{
        id : 2,
        parent_id : 1,
        text: 'Первый уровень 1'
    },{
        id : 3,
        parent_id : 1,
        text: 'Первый уровень 2'
    },{
        id : 4,
        parent_id : 2,
        text: 'Второй уровень'
    },{
        id : 5,
        parent_id : 4,
        text: 'Третий уровень уровень 1'
    },{
        id : 6,
        parent_id : 4,
        text: 'Третий уровень уровень 2'
    }];
```

Ищу алгоритм построения дерева такого типа:
Где дети вложены в родитель в JSON формате.

```
var data = [{
        name: 'Корень',
        id: 1,
        parent_id : 1,
        children: [{
            name: 'Первый уровень 1',
            id: 2,
            parent_id : 1,
            children: [{
                name: 'Второй уровень',
                id: 4,
                parent_id : 2
                children: [{
                    name: 'Третий уровень уровень 1',
                    parent_id : 4,
                    id: 5
                },{
                    name: 'Третий уровень уровень 2',
                    parent_id : 4,
                    id: 6
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Первый уровень 2',
            id: 3,
            parent_id : 1
        }]
    }];
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: у id=1 родитель, по идее, должен быть 0. А так, задача не самая сложная. Можно прям тупо найти корень, а потом рекурсивно искать, тех кто ссылается на текущий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = [{
        id : 1,
        parent_id : 1,
        text: 'Корень'
    },{
        id : 2,
        parent_id : 1,
        text: 'Первый уровень 1'
    },{
        id : 3,
        parent_id : 1,
        text: 'Первый уровень 2'
    },{
        id : 4,
        parent_id : 2,
        text: 'Второй уровень'
    },{
        id : 5,
        parent_id : 4,
        text: 'Третий уровень уровень 1'
    },{
        id : 6,
        parent_id : 4,
        text: 'Третий уровень уровень 2'
    }];

// сначала приведём в соответствие позицию объекта и его id
// но, что бы не изменять исходный объект, мы создадим другой
const output = [];

for (const item of input) {
  // т.к. минимальный идентификатор элемента равен 1,
  // вычтем из идентификатора единицу, что бы задействовать
  // индекс 0 (но можно этого и не делать)
  output[item.id - 1] = item;
}

// теперь, в массиве output идентификатор каждого элемента
// соответствует его позии в массиве

// далее, присвоим каждому родителю его детей
for (const item of output) {
  if (item.id !== item.parent_id) {
    // не забываем, что мы вычитали из каждого идентификатора
    // единицу по этому и здесь тоже вычитаем
    const parent = output[item.parent_id - 1];

    // убедимся, что родительский элемент 
    // имеет свойство children
    if (!Array.isArray(parent.children)) {
      parent.children = [];
    }

    // добавляем текущий элемент родителю
    parent.children.push(item);
  }
}

// в итоге, элемент с индексом 0 всегда будет представлять
// из себя полное дерево
console.log(output[0]);
```

Comment: А еще код не по стандарту js5. У меня неправильно работал.
Если id имеют разные значения например 118, 119, 130 и идут не по порядку, то не работает код.

poseidon.js:8500 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.createJson (poseidon.js:8500)
    at Object.prepareData (poseidon.js:8534)
    at Object.showFolders (poseidon.js:8641)
    at poseidon.js:16379
    at poseidon.js:14863
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (poseidon.js:2733)

Comment: Завел отдельную переменную count 

 var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            item = input[i];
            // т.к. минимальный идентификатор элемента равен 1,
            // вычтем из идентификатора единицу, что бы задействовать
            // индекс 0 (но можно этого и не делать)
            output[count] = item;
            count++;
        }